What is the name of the tool to view XML property and element？
I'm looking up the 3MF specification and interested in the tool to view XML property and element(See below).
It is easy to read the element, property, type, counts of element in XML, I like to learn more about it. However, I google and can't find any useful information. Please tell me what is the name of tool, thanks.


Ultimately Cura: Cura is software used to open 3MF files which contain necessary information about 3D models. In addition to this, Cura loads information about the filament type, print settings, and nozzle size. Prusa Slicer: Prusa slicer is compatible with the 3MF file format and some other file formats as well.

@jdweng I'm not to find a software to view a 3MF file, but just to find a tool view a xml file.

XML is text and any text editor will open an Xml.  Your picture is a Cura Model and you want to view the model.  You said "interested in the tool to view XML property"
